# Node.jsでwavファイルを保存する方法

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, websocket

Node.jsを用いてwavファイルを保存する際、
WebAudioAPIで録音したデータをどのような形にして
fs.writeFile()に渡せばよいのかわからず困っています。

◆開発環境
win 10
goole chrome ver55.0.2883.87 m
Node.js ver6.7.0
Web Audio API
recorder.js

現在、音声録音自体はWeb Audio APIを使用し、
wavファイルへの変換はrecorder.js
(参考：https://labs.irohasoft.com/webaudio/chrome/)
を用いて行っているのですが、fs.writeFileでwavファイルを
保存する方法が分からず四苦八苦しています。

◆クライアントサイド
音声録音はWebAudioAPIを使用しており、
recorder.jsでwavファイルに変換しています。
以下はwavファイル変換部分のコードです。

```
recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var hf = document.createElement('a');

    hf.href = url;
    hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
    hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
    voiceBuff = ?;
});
```

voiceBuffはmodule.exportsで準備した変数で
fs.writeFile()の第二引数として利用したいと考えているのですが、
?の部分に何を渡せばよいのか見当がつかず悩んでいます。

◆共通のjsファイル(common.js)

```
var voiceBuff;

(function (exports) {
    exports.getVoice = function(){return voiceBuff};
})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this.mymodule = {} : exports);
```

◆サーバサイド

```
var fs     = require('fs');
var common = require('./js/common.js');

・・・

fs.writeFile(
    'rec01.wav',
    common.getVoice(),
    function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

勉強不足のため誤った箇所やわかりにくい部分など
多々あるとは思いますが、何かわからない部分があれば
随時追記していきます。
ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

◆クライアント側
XMLHttpRequest を使ってバイナリデータをPOSTする
[バイナリデータの送信](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_binary_data)

◆サーバサイド
POSTされたbodyを保存する
[Node.jsでフォームからアップロードされたファイルを保存する](http://qiita.com/naga3/items/6eca632ffcfd14dba873)

で解決しました。